# handling routes in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

so I've a simple web application built without angular.

http://niteshsharma.com/js.metalist/

if you hit on the list item it will update URL with **index.html#/:listId**
and if you hit task it will update URL with **index.html#/:listId/:taskId**
all the communication between different component was happening using routes through hashchange event instead of global event bus which was also maintaining states.

I was trying to implement the exact same thing in angular but i am not sure How to do it without using some hackish code.

I've checked $routeProvider and $uiRouter services but I am not sure how to fit them in this scenario and avoid whole page re rendering

Comment: try watching $location.url()

Answer (score 0):

Did you try basic angularjs [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)?